# ResourceSet.createResource(URI) - what if 'uri' is not enough to create certain resource?

Tags: eclipse-emf

There is a method in ResourceSet which can create resource:

public Resource createResource(URI uri)

The problem: 'uri' is not enough to create valid type of resource.
For example, if the uri is like this: "http://host/file.wsdl" then createResource will understand that WSDLResource should be created.
But what if I have a wsdl with, say, such url: "http://host/file?wsdl"
How should I say ResourceSet that "WSDLResource" should be created?

Of course I can extract at runtime actual type of resource going to be created, but i don't know how to pass this type to ResourceSet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`ResourceSet.createResource(URI uri, String contentType)`](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/ResourceSet.html#createResource(org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI,%20java.lang.String)). You just need to know the content type identifier for your particular resource type in the registry.